# Aptana3 Save and Upload Files

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I'm trying to move from Quanta Plus to Aptana3 for my web development projects. I downloaded Aptana 3, stand-alone version. Thus far, it has been an excellent replacement, with many great features. However, there is one essential feature that may be seen as an obvious and serious omission.

In Quanta Plus, the upload command automatically saves a file before initiating the transfer. I could assign a keyboard command to save/upload very easily.

In Aptana3, you have to manually save the file before uploading it or 'Deploy'.

I tried to record a macro to recover this functionality by selecting 'Save' and 'Upload' in the Edit Macro window and adding them on the right pane. Unfortunately this did not work.

Is there a way to programmatically add this feature in Aptana3, either in javascript or bundles?

Your input will be greatly appreciated!

Alan.

Comment: By the way, the "Autosync" in the Deployment settings isn't a viable option because live site's files may be overwritten with test files.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ticket currently filed on the feature: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2229.